# Azure OnDemand WebJob status changed to Aborted

Tags: azure, console, azure-webjobs

I'm working with Azure WebJobs, converting my task schedulers to WebJobs (my task scheduler is an .exe) When I run the WebJob OnDemand, after it runs for 4 to 5 hours its status is changing to **Aborted** and my data is not updated in my database. When I Googled this, I found one potential solution regarding Graceful Shutdown [here](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/05/webjobs-graceful-shutdown/#.VNqThvmG8oc):

```
 The graceful period can be updated for any WebJob, the way to do 
 it is to create a file called settings.job with the following content: 
 { "stopping_wait_time": 60 }
```

I've tried this, adding the property `"stopping_wait_time": 1800` to my settings.job file and put the file in my site at `app_Data/jobs/myjobname/myjobname/settings.job`

However, this hasn't helped me. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you find any error logs written to your job output directory (`data/jobs/triggered/{jobName}`)?

Comment: Also note that OnDemand/Triggered WebJobs are automatically aborted if they have no output or CPU activity for a period of time. This is governed by the **WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT** app setting (default is 120 seconds). This is described more in the wiki page: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs

Comment: @mathewc sorry to intimate here I already added therse two properties: WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT and SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT  in my azure app setting

Comment: there is no error in log file

Comment: It also happens to me. It was bcz of, my web jobs was giving code error after few minutes. That may be the same issue in your case, please verify your code.

Comment: hi dsa, thanxs for reply , I found the issue that dlls issue